# "First time here" banner suggests visiting the FAQ regardless of current page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I don't usually go on Super User, but I wanted to check something in its FAQ so I went directly to https://superuser.com/faq. I got the "First time here? Check out the FAQ!" banner at the top, which should probably be suppressed if the user happens to be on the FAQ page at the time. I'm assuming this happens on all the sites and not just SU so I'm filing it here

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96084/recursive-link-when-privileges-unlocked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Welcome" banner itself has been removed, so marking this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Answer (score 4):

This is The Team's attempt at educating people of the dangers of infinite recursion.

Or put differently, to understand the FAQ you must first understand the FAQ

Comment: We need an FAQ entry for "Where is the FAQ?"

Comment: @Michael: Sounds like "Trust me, I'm a liar"

Answer (score 0):

Just register once, and that banner won't come back again.

Comment: Well yes, but that wasn't really my point :)

Comment: @Michael: the FAQ is generally not the first page people go to. Generally if they go, they go kicking and screaming. I see your point, but might be a bit of an edge-case to bother about.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds just fine to me: *displaying* the FAQ and *checking it out* are not necessarily related... ;-)

(Note that actually clicking "FAQ" in that message does make it go away right away. I guess most people will use that route to get to the FAQ?)