# Recursive link when "privileges unlocked"

Tags: feature-request, support

When I unlock something and get the bar at the top, I'll navigate to that page, but the "Learn more" thing that links to that page is on that page.

Click the link, and it goes...to that page, and displays that bar..and we have an infinite loop =P Here is a picture:
[image: Recursive link]

As you can see, I am on the page to learn about viewing close votes, but I still have the option to navigate to this exact page. It's not really a huge deal, but in my opinion there should be some detection to see what page you're on- if you're simply on the page you need to be, don't display this bar.

Comment: Please don't take this personally, but I'm downvoting you. On meta sites, downvotes just indicate disagreement with a feature request or opinion. This is a valid, well-written question -- the kind we need more of, honestly -- and I hope you stick around!

Comment: Yep I read the FAQ lol. I'm not really out for reputation, but possible betterment of the community? Definitely.

Comment: To explain why I disagree: all the notification bars are set to stick around until they're acted on to be closed. I think special-casing the behavior for privilege notifications, as tied to specific site pages, would be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: @Popular ~ What if we did it for ALL such links that had a "link to" target? For instance "You've earned the Great Question badge for this Q ...."

Comment: @Popular There's already an exception for badges; if you click the "go to your profile" link it dismisses the notification bar

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92653/dismiss-the-notification-bar-when-i-click-any-link-contained-within-it

Comment: @Jon I see! I couldn't find that in my searches =(

Comment: @Michael, oh, okay. I guess I never click on badge notification "see your profile" links.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47531/first-time-here-banner-suggests-visiting-the-faq-regardless-of-current-page

Answer (score 2):

More specifically, if you navigate to that page, then remove the bar as tho you had clicked the X specifically.