# Why is there no "Hello World" box on homepage for unregistered users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

When you follow a link from search engines etc. you see the Hello World box on the right if you are an unregistered user.

[image]

Why does not this same block show on Stackoverflow homepage for the same purposes? Is it a SEO consideration?

Comment: This is intentional - we are trying to make the anonymous user experience somewhat different from the logged in user.

Comment: @Oded The difference is not between logged in vs anonymous. This is the same user experience for the anonymous on homepage and subpages.

Comment: We are making changes one page at a time... we will get to the questions page too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]We will be replacing this box with something a little prettier and more front and center. It will be dismissible into a thin horizontal strip across the top of the page.

If you haven't noticed, we have also removed a lot of cruft in the right sidebar for anonymous users.

Our intention is to focus more on what is relevant instead of throwing everything at users and hoping something sticks.

Comment: Could we get the recent tags and recent badges removed for logged in users as well? They don't really serve any useful purpose in my opinion.

Comment: We wanted to make the volume of changes as small as possible, so we will be welcoming feedback on meta to decide how much of this stuff gets ported over for registered users.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell: remove stuff until people whine on meta. Anything which ends up positively voted on meta should be put back, the rest can stay gone.

Comment: "It will be dismissible into a thin horizontal strip across the top of the page." [Hmmm...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129118/why-was-the-welcome-banner-removed)

Comment: @MadScientist Recent tags is kinda useless, but the recent badges is nice on smaller sites.  I often find some really good answers/questions I've overlooked when I see something like a Great Answer badge show up on that list.  Not showing bronze badges and shortening the number shown (5? 10?) would be OK too though.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Not that banner...

Comment: FWIW, I really like the changes you're bringing about...

Comment: @LoremIpsum Thanks. It takes a while to get the gears moving, and I think we're just in the cleanup phase right now. Lots of good stuff in the pipeline.